# How to do dropdowns with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a dropdown with a react component and the anchor tags do not render. The anchors should be on the dropdown when clicked, however they don't appear. If `getItems()` fails, the default dropdown should just say loading. Any suggestions about the dropdown?

Dropdown.js

```
<li className="nav-item dropdown">
  <a className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <img src={shoppingCart} alt="shopping cart" className="" style={{ width: "30px", height: "30px"}}></img>
  </a>
  <div className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <CartItems></CartItems>
  </div>
</li>
```

CartItems.js

```
export default function CartItems() {

    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    const [itemsRef, setItemsRef] = useState([]);


    async function getItems() {
        if(currentUser !== null) {
            const q = query(collection(db, currentUser.uid));
            console.log('q', q);
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
            console.log("snapshot", querySnapshot);
            setItemsRef(querySnapshot);
            console.log('items', itemsRef)
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            });
        }
       
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems();
    }, [])

    if(itemsRef !== undefined && itemsRef !== null && itemsRef.length !== 0) {
    return(
        <>
            {
                itemsRef.forEach((item, index) => {
                    return <CartItem key={index} item={item} />
                })
            }
        </>
    );
    } else {
        return <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">Loading Cart...</a>
    }
}
```

CartItem.jsx

```
class cartItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            
        }
    }
    render() { 
        return <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
            <img src={this.props.item.image} style={{width: "10px", height: "17px"}}></img>
            <p>{this.props.item.title}</p>
            <button ></button>
        </a>
    }
}
 
export default cartItem;
```

Any reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. "they don't appear" Instead of describing what does**n't** appear, can you show us what *does* appear?

Comment: I apologize. When clicked the dropdown doesn't pop up at all. The url just changes to /# and that is the only change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that querySnapshot is an object and needs to be converted into an array.

```
async function getItems() {
        if(currentUser !== null) {
            const q = query(collection(db, currentUser.uid));
            console.log('q', q);
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
            console.log("snapshot", querySnapshot);
            
            let array = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                array.push(doc.data());
            });
            // console.log(array);
            setItemsRef(itemsRef => [...itemsRef, array]);
            console.log('items', itemsRef);
        }
       
    }
```

And the dropdown need to be done with react bootstrap

```
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown'

<Dropdown.Menu>
    <CartItem />
</Dropdown.Menu>
```

Where CartItem countains a `<Dropdown.Item>`.